# how to reduce the processing cost of comparing many strings together in Python?

Tags: python, string, performance

I have two datasets, A and B, that contain a string variable similar to a headline.

example : "this is a very nice string".

Both datasets are large (millions of observations).

I need to see whether the strings in A also appear somewhere in B. I was wondering if there is a specific Python library that would reduce the computational cost of comparing some many strings together?

Maybe via some smart indexing of the datasets before running the comparison? Any idea/suggestion is welcome.

Important problem: matching should be fuzzy, because I can have the following headlines

A: "this is an apple"
B: "this is a red apple"

they dont match perfectly, but they are really close. If there is not better matching (such as exact matching) then I consider they are the same.

Many thanks

Comment: Use the set datatype. It has `O(1)` performance for membership testing and `O(n)` storage

Comment: how the datasets are stored?

Comment: I can store them in whatever format I want to

Comment: maybe should you use a database such sqlite or postgres

Comment: Do you have formal definition of "really close"? Are you comparing just words or you are ok if there are some typos("I like apples" and "I like appkes")?

Comment: just a sentence with proper words. there wont be any typos. What I mean by close is when a headline from A contains most of the words from a headline from B.

Comment: you could store your dataset in a text file and create index on it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532312/python-file-indexing-and-searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Whoosh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/) is a fast, featureful full-text indexing and searching library implemented in pure Python. Programmers can use it to easily add search functionality to their applications and websites. Every part of how Whoosh works can be extended or replaced to meet your needs exactly.

Documentation: [Whoosh package documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/)

Home Page: http://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh

Comment: do you have experience with that package? Can it support very large datasets?

Comment: I dont know, you will have to tell me

Answer (score 1):

One option is to convert the two datasets to python `set` and check whether the set of `A` is subset of the set of `B`. You should experiment what is the complexity, but I believe python code is pretty optimized.

Other option is to build [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of the strings in `B`. This will take `O(|B| * max_str_len_in_B)`. After that you will iterate over the strings in `A` and check if everyone of them is in the trie. This will cost you `O(|A| * max_str_len_in_A)`.

Comment: thank you very much. Please see the edited post. sorry about the confusion.