# Fastest way to search a 12GB file using python

Tags: python, search, mmap

I'd like to perform 4000+ searches for strings in a 12GB text file.

Currently, I'm using `mmap` to load the file into memory, which is works well (takes about 5 seconds):

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
    data = m.read(-1)
```

Unfortunately, the searching is taking forever:

```
for string_to_search_for in list_of_queries:
    if string_to_search_for in data:
        print "Found a match!"
```

How can I speed the searching up?

Comment: Load text file into a database and use the database instead, if it's an option

Comment: Multithreading?

Comment: Try at the very least with a regular expression that runs all the searches in one go. Currently you are looping over all the data multiple times. And ... well .. searching through 12 GB of data from disk will take a while.

Comment: @MatTheWhale That probably would thrash the page cache. It's a linear search and CPython's mmap implementation doesn't [implement any efficient search algorithm](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/da5e9301877346942fa4279612750d6a09e05153/Modules/mmapmodule.c#L299), meaning the problem is most likely IO bound.

Answer (score 0):

index the file, and then apply your searches.  you may use lucene to do this in a better way. have a look at this thread [Python file indexing and searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532312/python-file-indexing-and-searching)